# How to Set Limit with WordPress Get Bookmarks Shortcode

Tags: plugins, php, shortcode, links, blog

I just need some help with a WordPress shortcode function. I would like to create a list of links based on the link_category inside a post with a shortcode. I had the shortcode working until I added the limit argument to the function. So Basically can someone help me correct this problem? The code can be seen below, as copied from my functions.php file. Please note that I am no php expert, but I can edit/break existing code like a champ. The site in question is http://linuxlibrary.org

I appreciate the help!

```
add_shortcode('lynx', 'lynx_shortcode_handler');

function lynx_shortcode_handler($atts)
{
    // extract parameters
    $parms = shortcode_atts(array(
        'cat_name' => 'Learn More',
        'limit' => '5',
        'use_description' => 'false',
        'use_image' => 'false',
        'before_line' => '<li>',
        'after_line' => '</li>
',
        'before_content' => '<ul>
',
        'after_content' => '</ul>
',
        'target' => '',
        'xfn' => '',
        ), $atts);

    $cat_name = $parms['cat_name'];
    $use_description = strtolower($parms['use_description']);
    $limit = $parms['limit'];
    $use_image = strtolower($parms['use_image']);
    $before_line = $parms['before_line'];
    $after_line = $parms['after_line'];
    $before_content = $parms['before_content'];
    $after_content = $parms['after_content'];
    $target = $parms['target'];
    $xfn = $parms['xfn'];

    // process t/f options
    $b_use_description = false;
    if (($use_description == 'yes') || ($use_description == 'y') ||
        ($use_description == 'true') || ($use_description == '1'))
    {$b_use_description = true;}

    $b_use_image = false;
    if (($use_image == 'yes') || ($use_image == 'y') ||
        ($use_image == 'true') || ($use_image == '1'))
    {$b_use_image = true;}

    // exit
    return lynx($cat_name, $b_use_description,
        $b_use_image, $before_line,
        $after_line, $before_content,
        $after_content, $target, $xfn);

}


}

function lynx(
    $cat_name='Learn More',
    $limit='5',
    $use_description='1',
    $use_image='1',
    $before_line='<li>',
    $after_line='</li>
',
    $before_content='<ul>
',
    $after_content='</ul>
',
    $target='',
    $xfn='')
{

    // get the data
    $args = array('limit' => $limit,
            'orderby' => 'rating',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'category_name' => $cat_name);
    $bookmarks = get_bookmarks($args);

    // process the data
    $output = $before_content;
    foreach ($bookmarks as $bmk)
    {
        $bmk_link = $bmk->link_url;
        $bmk_name = $bmk->link_name;
        $bmk_description = $bmk->link_description;
        $bmk_image = $bmk->link_image; // works best with icons (like favicon.ico)
        $href = '<a rel="' . $xfn . '" href="' . $bmk_link . '" target="' . $target . '">' . $bmk_name . '</a>';

        $output .= $before_line;
        if ($use_image == '1')
        {
            // assumes 16x16 icons and aligns margin accordingly
            // MSIE has issues with some favicon.ico files
            $output .= '<img src="' . $bmk_image . '" width="16" height="16" style="margin-bottom:-2px;" />&nbsp;';
        }
        $output .= $href;
        if ($use_description == '1')
        {
            $output .= ' ' . $bmk_description;
        }
        $output .= $after_line;
    }

    // exit
    $output = $output . $after_content;
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: I would like the default limit set to 4, with the option to add manual arguments to the shortcode in posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to not be passing `$limit` in your call to `lynx()`. Here is the corrected version:

```
return lynx($cat_name, $limit $b_use_description,
    $b_use_image, $before_line,
    $after_line, $before_content,
    $after_content, $target, $xfn);
```

Comment: Thats great, I'll give it a try now.

Comment: Seems to have worked just fine. I will continue to test it for further tweaks. Thanks again for the quick response! This really helps!

Comment: Confirmed after testing output further. Everything seems to be working well. Thank you very much for the help.